# Class-level annotation in bean validation doesn't allow to retrieve the name of the fields

Tags: java, jersey

I have an api like this, using Jersey 2 and Java:

```
@POST
@Path("/doorder")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces("text/plain")
public String doOrder(@BeanParam @Valid OrderBean orderBean) {

    // Code here
}
```

As you can see above all the user input is stored into this bean:

```
@AllOrNone(group="address")
public final class OrderBean {

    @Group(name="address")
    @FormDataParam("address")
    private String address;

    @Group(name="address")
    @FormDataParam("city")
    private String city;

    @Group(name="address")
    @FormDataParam("postcode")
    private String postcode;

    // Getters and setters

}
```

I used a class-level annotation that I created, called "AllOrNone", where all the fields or none have to contain valid values.
However in the ExceptionMapper where I build a response in case the validation fails, I don't have information about the name of the fields in the group or the name of the group:

```
@Provider
public class ConstraintViolationMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException e) {

       // here no clue about the name of the group or the fields involved
    }
}
```

How can I get the name of the fields or the name of the group in the above code?

EDIT:

Here I also add the code used to create the annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,
    ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = AllOrNoneValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface AllOrNone {
    String message() default "Group of fields should have all fields or none";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    String group();
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And here the validator code:

```
public final class AllOrNoneValidator extends GroupValidator implements ConstraintValidator<AllOrNone, Object> {

    private String group;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final AllOrNone constraintAnnotation) {

    this.group = constraintAnnotation.group();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Object bean, final ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

    // some code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation> violations = e.getConstraintViolations();

for (ConstraintViolation violation : violations) {
    String property = violation.getPropertyPath().getName();
}
```

Comment: I tried but it returns "doOrder.arg0". Nothing really useful. I need to know the nome of the group or the name of the fields belonging the group.

Comment: @user1883212 If you are using Java 8, try compiling with parameter names.

Comment: tried to compile with "-parameters" but still getting the same

Comment: @user1883212 If you are using Hibernate Validator as Bean Validation implementation, you need to configure a `ParameterNameProvider`. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-parameter-name-provider).